# How to add new item to dictionary in loop using uniquely generated string based on index? (Python)

Tags: python, string-formatting, typeerror

I have array x[], which could be of any length. For context, each item in the array is a Deal ID.

I run a loop to pass each Deal ID into a SOQL query to capture each deal's information and store it in a unique variable that carries its array index (i.e. for deal at index x[0] the unique variable name is string0). Then I create an empty dictionary LDdates = {}. This process works as expected.

However, when I attempt to add a new item to dictionary LDdates, with the key as a value from the deal's OrderedDict (which is captured in line 2), and the value as a value from the deal's OrderedDict, I get the following error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

My code:

```
    for i in range(len(x)):
        globals()['string%s' % i] = sf.deal__c.get('%s' % x[i])
        LDdates = {}
        LDdates['%s' % ('string%s'['Id'] % i)] = '%s' % ('string%s'['due_date__c'] % i)
```

My questions are: Why am I seeing this error? What do I need to change in order for it to work? Lines 1-3 work as expected. Line 4 presents the TypeError.

Comment: Yeah, the error is pretty clear, what do you expect `'string%s'['Id']` to do?

Comment: Aside: who suggested that you use `globals()` to dynamically construct variables and pollute your namespace instead of just using a list or dictionary?  Because that person is not your friend.

Comment: You're employing a rather *unique* programming style.

Comment: To add to the previous comments - each iteration resets `LDates` to an empty dictionary. Not sure what you're trying to do with that.

Comment: @timgeb 'string%s'['Id'] should populate the key field with an Id that is given as a value within the OrderedDict stored in variable 'string%s' % i. Same story for the value field, except that should populate a due date.

Comment: @Philosopher well, you can't use a string as an index for a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this:

```
LDates['%s' % ('string%s'['Id'] % i)]
```

I believe that you mean to access the variable you created earlier. That would require you to use:

```
LDates[(globals()['string%s' % i])['Id']]
```

But this whole thing is ill-advised. Why don't you create a variable where you can access all the data by just passing in the integer `i`? That would be a `list`!

```
Deals = [ sf.deal__c.get(id) for id in x ]
```

Then set `LDates` to map `Id` to `due_date__c`:

```
LDates = {d['Id']:d['due_date__c'] for d in Deals}
```